# Como validar com regex uma string contendo apenas letras, espaços em branco e letras com acento?

Tags: javascript, regex, acentuação

Estou querendo validar um `input text` para nome completo a fim de aceitar apenas letras, espaços em branco e letras com acento.

Formatos válidos:

```
Leandro Moreira  
leandro moreira  
Kézia Maria  
kezia maria  
Cabaço da silva  
Cabaço da Silva
```

Esse regex não pode aceitar caracteres especiais fora letras com acento.

Comment: Como sugerido no artigo abaixo, você pode usar o seguinte padrão: /[À-ü]/
https://medium.com/xp-inc/regex-um-guia-pratico-para-express%C3%B5es-regulares-1ac5fa4dd39f

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Se o alvo são apenas os acentos comuns em português, fica fácil listá-los um a um. Eu faria uma regex com os seguintes blocos:

- `A-Za-z` maiúsculas e minúsculas sem acento
- `áàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ`: vogais acentuadas do português, cedilha e umas outras de lambuja, minúsculas
- `ÁÀÂÃÉÈÊÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ`: vogais acentuadas do português, cedilha e umas outras de lambuja, maiúsculas
- espaços

Portanto:

```
/^[A-Za-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ ]+$/
```

Ou, deixando a distinção minúsculas/maiúsculas para a implementação:

```
/^[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ ]+$/i
```

**[Demo (desta segunda opção)](http://www.regexr.com/38rdr)**

Comment: Uma outra alternativa a definir todos os caracteres na unha (para quem precisa de caracteres universais) é o [XRegExp Unicode](http://xregexp.com/plugins/). Com ele você pode usar [categorias Unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) como `\p{L}`. Mas realmente validação de nome me soa como algo que pode dar problemas.

Comment: @bfavaretto testei o regsx aqui mas ele ainda aceita números. o que eu posso fazer para não permitir isso?

Comment: @LeandroCurioso Estava ocorrendo um *match* parcial do nome. Acrescentei `^` no início e `$` no fim da expressão para que compare com o nome completo. Ver http://jsfiddle.net/C2Xcp/

Comment: Perfeito! Resolvi com esse regex ^[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÊÍÏÓÒÖÚÇÑ ]+$

Answer (score 33):

Gostei mais da solução do bfavaretto, mas vou deixar uma alternativa mais curta aqui:

```
var reg = /[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00FF ]+/i
```

Explicação: isso é um match dos caracteres 'a' até o 'z', 'A' até o 'Z', e finalmente, de todos os caracteres Unicode do 'À' até o 'ÿ', então acho que deve englobar todos os caracteres acentuados.

A lista completa dos caracteres latinos em Unicode pode ser vista aqui: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/list.htm

A lista completa contém cerca de 128 caracteres, dos quais utilizamos apenas uma parte. A expressão que eu usei inclui alguns estranhos e improváveis, como o Æ e ao menos dois sinais matemáticos. Talvez você queira usar uma expressão mais precisa como a do bfavaretto, ou utilizar faixas mais estreitas do Unicode.

Comment: Boa solução! O único problema é que esse range de unicode inclui `×` e `÷`.

Answer (score 15):

Completando a resposta do bfavareto, quando for colocar código de expressão regular para nomes, lembrar que podemos ter situações como Antônio D'Ávila. Nestes casos, inserir também o apóstrofe. E o espaço é interessante deixar pra máquina, com o \s:

`/^[A-Za-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ'\s]+$/`

Comment: `\s` casa `[ \n\r\t\f]`

Comment: Muito bom. Essa é a solução mais completa! Realmente existe esse apóstrofe no idioma Português Brasileiro.

Comment: Em vez do \s, podes colocar apenas um espaço mesmo (para não apanhar o que o @Mariano referiu)

Comment: E para evitar apanhar uma string que só tenha espaços, pode-se verificar com um `isEmpty()` e `trim()`

Answer (score 10):

Apenas um detalhe: em várias das outras respostas foi usada uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) contendo o espaço (como `/^[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ ]+$/i`, por exemplo - repare que tem um espaço dentro dos colchetes). Não está errado, mas o problema é que esta regex também considera válidas strings que só tem espaços:

```js
console.log(/^[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ ]+$/i.test('     ')); // true
```

Neste caso, talvez fosse melhor fazer o [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) da string, separando-a por espaços, e em seguida verificar se cada uma das partes é um nome válido (ou seja, se tem somente letras):

```js
let nomes = [ 'Leandro Moreira', 'leandro moreira', 'Kézia Maria', 'kezia maria',
              'Cabaço da silva', 'Cabaço da Silva', 'Fulano A123', '     '];
// removi o espaço da regex (agora ela só considera as letras)
let regex = /^[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]+$/i;
nomes.forEach(nome => {
    let valido = nome.split(/ +/).every(parte => regex.test(parte));
    console.log(`${nome} = ${valido ? 'válido': 'inválido'}`);
});
```

O `split` é feito considerando-se [um ou mais](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) espaços como separador (`/ +/` - repare que há um espaço antes do `+`). Também seria possível usar `/\s+/`, mas o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s` também considera o <kbd>TAB</kbd> e quebras de linha (além de outros caracteres, veja a lista completa na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-white-space) - lembrando também que esta lista [varia de uma linguagem para outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052)). Se isso faz diferença, vai depender das strings que você está verificando.

O `split` retorna um array contendo as partes do nome. Depois, eu uso o [método `every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), que verifica se todas as partes correspondem à regex (que por sua vez verifica se tem somente letras). Se alguma delas não corresponder, o retorno é `false`.

Outro detalhe é que o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências", o que quer dizer que strings como `'a b c'` também seriam consideradas válidas (já que, após o `split`, cada parte do "nome" teria uma letra). Se quiser que cada parte do nome tenha uma quantidade mínima (e/ou máxima) de letras, pode trocar o `+` por `{}`. Exemplos:

- `[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]{2,}`: no mínimo 2 caracteres (sem limite máximo)
- `[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]{2,20}`: no mínimo 2, no máximo 20 caracteres
- `[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]{10}`: exatamente 10 caracteres

Use o que fizer mais sentido no seu caso.

---

Uma outra opção é usar o [método `normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) (que [já possui um bom suporte dos browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize#Browser_compatibility)), juntamente com outra regex, para remover os acentos, e aí bastaria verificar por letras de `a` a `z`:

```js
let nomes = [ 'Leandro Moreira', 'leandro moreira', 'Kézia Maria', 'kezia maria',
              'Cabaço da silva', 'Cabaço da Silva', 'Tomas Müller', 'Fulano A123', '     '];
// não precisa mais das letras acentuadas
let regex = /^[a-z]+$/i;
nomes.forEach(nome => {
    let valido = nome
        // remove os acentos
        .normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
        // aqui é igual ao código anterior
        .split(/ +/).every(parte => regex.test(parte));
    console.log(`${nome} = ${valido ? 'válido': 'inválido'}`);
});
```

De forma bem resumida, a normalização para a forma NFD "quebra" um caractere acentuado em dois. Por exemplo, o `ã` é quebrado (ou decomposto) em dois caracteres: o `a` minúsculo (sem nenhum acento) e o til (`~`). (para mais detalhes sobre normalização, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052)).

Em seguida, eu removo os caracteres do intervalo `\u0300-\u036f`, que corresponde ao bloco Unicode ["Combining Diacritical Marks"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/combining_diacritical_marks/list.htm), que é onde ficam os caracteres de acentuação (como o [til](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0303/index.htm), entre outros). Sendo assim, só sobram as letras sem acento, e eu posso verificá-las com a regex `[a-z]` (juntamente com a [*flag* `i`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters), que torna a regex *case insensitive*, portanto já considera tanto letras maiúsculas e minúsculas).

Repare no exemplo acima o caso de `Müller`, que a primeira regex não pegou (mas que é facilmente resolvido adicionando o `ü` na lista: `[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñü ]`). Enfim, cabe a você escolher se quer manter uma lista fixa, ou usar algo mais genérico (tudo depende das nacionalidades dos nomes que você vai tratar e dos tipos de caracteres que podem aparecer).

---

Obs: existem ainda outros intervalos que contém caracteres "de acentuação" (na verdade, "Diacritical Marks"), como o ["Combinining Diacritical Marks Suplement"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/combining_diacritical_marks_supplement/list.htm) e o ["Combining Diacritical Marks Extended"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/combining_diacritical_marks_extended/list.htm), entre outros. Esses blocos possuem *diacritical marks* que não são usados em português, então dependendo dos nomes que você quer validar, pode ser que não precise incluí-los no `replace`. Mas caso queira considerar também estes caracteres, ficaria `replace(/[\u0300-\u036f\u1dc0-\u1dff\u1ab0-\u1abe]/g, "")`.

Outra alternativa (que ainda não funciona em todos os browsers) é usar [*Unicode property escapes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes):

```js
let nomes = [ 'Leandro Moreira', 'leandro moreira', 'Kézia Maria', 'kezia maria',
              'Cabaço da silva', 'Cabaço da Silva', 'Tomas Müller', 'Fulano A123', '     '];
// não precisa mais das letras acentuadas
let regex = /^[a-z]+$/i;
nomes.forEach(nome => {
    let valido = nome
        // remove os acentos
        .normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{M}/ug, "")
        // aqui é igual ao código anterior
        .split(/ +/).every(parte => regex.test(parte));
    console.log(`${nome} = ${valido ? 'válido': 'inválido'}`);
});
```

Agora eu uso `\p{M}`, que pega todos os *combining characters*. Lembrando que nesse caso a regex tem que ter a [*flag* `u`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags) para que os *Unicode property escapes* funcionem. Verifique também se [o seu browser é compatível com este recurso](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#browser_compatibility).

---

## Nomes com apóstrofo e hífen

Por fim, não é requisito da pergunta, mas se a ideia é aceitar também nomes como apóstrofos ou hífens (como por exemplo [D'Margio Wright-Phillips](https://www.transfermarkt.com/dmargio-wright-phillips/profil/spieler/502062)), basta mudar a regex para `^[a-z]+(['\-][a-z]+)*$`:

```js
let nomes = [ "D'Margio Wright-Phillips", 'Leandro Moreira', 'leandro moreira', 'Kézia Maria', 'kezia maria',
              'Cabaço da silva', 'Cabaço da Silva', 'Tomas Müller', 'Fulano A123', '     '];
let regex = /^[a-z]+(['\-][a-z]+)*$/i;
nomes.forEach(nome => {
    let valido = nome
        // remove os acentos
        .normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{M}/ug, "")
        // aqui é igual ao código anterior
        .split(/ +/).every(parte => regex.test(parte));
    console.log(`${nome} = ${valido ? 'válido': 'inválido'}`);
});
```

---

Em [outra resposta](/a/583332/112052) foi sugerida a regex `^[\wà-ü']{2,}(\s+[\wà-ü']{2,})+$`, mas ela tem um problema: ela diz que `'''' ''''`, `123 456`, `__ __` e `÷÷÷ ÷÷÷` são nomes válidos. Isso porque a classe de caracteres `[\wà-ü']` diz que pode ser qualquer caractere incluso nela, e o quantificador `{2,}` diz que pode ter dois ou mais. Mas isso não diz **quais** podem aparecer (pode ser qualquer um deles, e não necessariamente serão as letras).

Por isso ela aceita `123 456` e `__ __`, já que o atalho `\w` considera não só letras, mas também dígitos e o caractere `_`. E isso condiz com `[\wà-ü']{2,}`, pois este trecho diz que podem ter dois ou mais caracteres que sejam `[\wà-ü']`. Pois é, **isso não obriga que tenha somente letras**, por isso esta regex acaba dando *match* em nomes inválidos. Quanto a `'''' ''''`, é a mesma coisa: o apóstrofo está dentro da classe de caracteres, então uma sequência de vários apóstrofos satisfaz `[\wà-ü']{2,}`. Já o caractere `÷` ([DIVISION SIGN](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f7/index.htm)) faz parte do intervalo `à-ü` (veja [aqui](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/list.htm)), por isso esta nem sempre é a melhor opção para verificar caracteres acentuados.

Só para efeito de comparação, veja como a solução que sugeri não considera esses nomes inválidos que citei, enquanto o código da outra resposta diz que são válidos:

```js
let nomes = [ "'''' ''''", "÷÷÷ ÷÷÷", "123 456", "__ __"];
let regex = /^[a-z]+(['\-][a-z]+)*$/i;
console.log('todos devem ser inválidos');
nomes.forEach(nome => {
    let valido = nome
        // remove os acentos
        .normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{M}/ug, "")
        // aqui é igual ao código anterior
        .split(/ +/).every(parte => regex.test(parte));
    console.log(`${nome} = ${valido ? 'válido': 'inválido'}`);
});

console.log('\nMas o código da outra resposta diz que são válidos:');
nomes.forEach(nome => {
  console.log(nome, ">", /^[\wà-ü']{2,}(\s+[\wà-ü']{2,})+$/i.test(nome));
});
```

Comment: Muito boa a sugestão, só acrescentei pro meu caso a verificação se existe o nome e ao menos um sobrenome, verificando se após o split o tamanho do array é maior do que 1 também.

Answer (score 7):

Se o sobrenome for obrigatório e houver apenas um campo a ser validado, pode-se usar o seguinte regex:

```
/\b[A-Za-zÀ-ú][A-Za-zÀ-ú]+,?\s[A-Za-zÀ-ú][A-Za-zÀ-ú]{2,19}\b/gi
```

Ele valida apenas letras, acentuação e espaço em branco. Não aceita números e cada string (nome) deve ter no mínimo 3 caracteres.

Demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/diafrit/toLd2yr2/1/)

Answer (score 5):

```
function removeSpecialCharSimple(strToReplace) {
strSChar = "áàãâäéèêëíìîïóòõôöúùûüçÁÀÃÂÄÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÕÖÔÚÙÛÜÇ";
strNoSChars = "aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucAAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC";
var newStr = "";
for (var i = 0; i < strToReplace.length; i++) {
    if (strSChar.indexOf(strToReplace.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        newStr += strNoSChars.substr(strSChar.search(strToReplace.substr(i, 1)), 1);
    } else {
        newStr += strToReplace.substr(i, 1);
    }
}

return newStr.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]/g, '');
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. E bom ver que tem vontade de responder, mas dedique algum tempo a explicar a sua resposta.

Comment: @drumerwhite usei sua função e ela foi muito útil, obrigado, adicionei ela no onkeyup="this.value = removeSpecialCharSimple(this.value);" , Obrigado !

Answer (score -2):

Todas as respostas aqui me deram bons insights, caso alguém precise, deixo aqui uma sugestão um pouco mais curta acrescentando as regras que mencionaram para validação de um nome completo:

```js
const nomes = [
  "Leandro Moreira",
  "leandro moreira",
  "Kézia Maria",
  "kezia maria",
  "Cabaço da silva",
  "Cabaço da Silva",
  "Joana D'Arc",
  "Jhonny",
  "1nome",
  " começa com espaco"
]

nomes.forEach(nome => {
  console.log(nome, ">", /^[\wà-ü']{2,}(\s+[\wà-ü']{2,})+$/i.test(nome))
})
```

- `^[\wà-ü']{2,}` > Valida a primeira parte do nome que deve começar com e conter apenas letras e apóstrofo, no mínimo dois caracteres;
- `(\s[\wà-ü']{2,})+$` > Valida o restante do nome que pode ter 1 espaço entre as partes do nome. Assim como a primeira validação, deve conter apenas letras e apóstrofo, no mínimo dois caracteres;
- `/i` > Aceita letras maiúsculas/minúsculas.

---

## Update

Após ler melhor a resposta do @hkotsubo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406366/13469), apenas incluí na implementação a validação de que deve conter o nome e ao menos 1 sobrenome.

Segue:

```js
const nomes = [
  "Leandro Moreira",
  "leandro moreira",
  "Kézia Maria",
  "kezia maria",
  "Cabaço da silva",
  "Cabaço da Silva",
  "Joana D'Arc",
  "Jhonny",
  "1nome",
  " começa com espaco",
  "'''' ''''",
  "÷÷÷ ÷÷÷",
  "123 456",
  "__ __"
]

const isValidName = (name) => {
  const namesWithoutAccent = /^[a-z]+(['\-][a-z]+)*$/i
  return namesWithoutAccent.test(name)
}

const isValidFullname = (fullname) => {
  const nameParts = fullname
    .normalize('NFD')
    .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '')
    .split(/ +/)

  // Verifica se todos os nomes seguem as regras e se possui ao menos nome e 1 sobrenome
  return nameParts.length > 1 && nameParts.every(isValidName)
}

nomes.forEach(nome => {
  console.log(nome, ">", isValidFullname(nome))
})
```

Comment: Por favor faça um teste com esse array: `nomes = [ "'''' ''''", "÷÷÷ ÷÷÷", "123 456", "__ __"];`. Sua regex vai dizer que todos são nomes válidos ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/aAPSMP)), quando claramente não são. Para mais detalhes, no final da [minha resposta](/a/406366/112052) eu explico porque isso acontece (e também tem uma solução para aceitar o apóstrofo, e principalmente, que não aceita esses nomes inválidos que indiquei).

Comment: Hmm, bem observado, obrigado. É sempre bom um downvote com alguma explicação do motivo, me ajudou aqui a entender um pouco melhor.

Comment: Em geral todo o downvote tem um motivo de ser dado. Se as pessoas levassem de forma madura e construtiva, como você fez, com certeza as pessoas se sentiriam mais a vontade para discutir os seus votos. O problema é que já ocorreram desrespeito, ofensas e até coisa pior por conta de justificativa de votos o gradualmente leu as pessoas a se calarem.

Answer (score -3):

Fala brother, tem uma regex simples para utilizar em suas validações:

```
const regex = /[^a-zA-Z\wÀ-ú ]/g;
```