# Regex para validação de nome com posix regex

Tags: regex

Eu tenho uma função em `c++` que valida nome e sobrenome com a seguinte `regex` :

```
"((?:[á-úA-Za-z]+[ ]+[á-úA-Za-z]{0,20})?)?"
```

estava dando uma olhada para deixar aprender a criar `regex` de outra forma com base no que esta aqui neste site:

https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html

entao eu fiz isso:

```
"((?:[[:alpha:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]{0,20})?)?"
```

mas nomes como César e Tião ele nao valida como eu faço isso com base nesse tipo de `regex`?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como validar com regex uma string contendo apenas letras, espaços em branco e letras com acento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15738/como-validar-com-regex-uma-string-contendo-apenas-letras-espa%c3%a7os-em-branco-e-le)

Comment: aquilo ali é para java estou fazendo para c++ tentei usar este link que vc marcou como duplicada para entender como suar posix regex mas nao achei nada que me faça aceitar nomes acentuados, alias se eu nao utilizar alpha ou apace usando letras ela valida tranquilamente...

Comment: Tente esta Regex: `[A-ZÀ-Ý][a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+\s*[A-ZÀ-Ý][a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+` e a [demo](http://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyyz00par). Nunca usei posix, mas o regexplanet aparentemente validou esta expressão em Posix.

Comment: o meu Deus eu nao estou falando disso esta regex: "((?:[á-úA-Za-z]+[ ]+[á-úA-Za-z]{0,20})?)?" valida nomes e sobrenomes com ou sem acentos se for pra trocar uma sintaxe pela outra nao vale a pena estou falando de utilizar algo como [:alpha:] [:alnum:] e fazer com base nisso com que seja reconhecidos comes com acentos..

Comment: Leia [esta referência](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) e você verá que o alpha não inclui acentuação. Portanto, você tem que usar: `[[:alpha:]À-ÿ]+`. Sugiro [ser mais específico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/707/coment%C3%A1rios-enlatados-para-situa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-comuns/1481#1481) nas sua perguntas, assim, há mais chances dela ser respondida corretamente. Inclusive utilizar as Tags corretas e dar exemplos num [mcve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: mais estecifico do que isso? Eu tenho uma função em c++ que valida nome e sobrenome com a seguinte regex :

"((?:[á-úA-Za-z]+[ ]+[á-úA-Za-z]{0,20})?)?"

estava dando uma olhada para deixar aprender a criar regex de outra forma com base no que esta aqui neste site:

https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html

entao eu fiz isso:

"((?:[[:alpha:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]{0,20})?)?"

mas nomes como César e Tião ele nao valida como eu faço isso com base nesse tipo de regex?