# Verificar se uma String contém duas palavras

Tags: java, string, validação

Estou com um problema nesse exercício aqui:

Escreva uma classe que faça a validação de dados (`Validacao`), com um método para validar um nome próprio (`ehNomeValido(nome)`). O método deve retornar `true` se passar pelas seguintes regras:

- Se o parâmetro não for nulo.
- Se o parâmetro não for uma `String` vazia
- Se o parâmetro tiver duas partículas (duas palavras separadas por um espaço)

O problema é que o programa só me retorna o `false` sendo que no caso do nome que eu coloquei como parâmetro o programa deveria retornar `true`. Onde estou errando? Já rescrevi o código várias vezes de outras formas e nada.

```
 public class NOVOTESTE2{

     public static boolean validacao(String nome){
         if((nome != null) && (nome.isEmpty() == false) && (nome.indexOf(" ") == 1)){
             return true;
         }else{
             return false;
         }     
     }

  public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(validacao("Rodrigo Moreira"));
  }  
}
```

Comment: Por favor, faça um titulo intuitivo para a pergunta, escrever Ajuda por favor é totalmente redundante, todos que estão perguntando no site já estão procurando por ajuda, então isso é óbvio, escrever um titulo util definindo o problema ajuda a aumentar o interesse das pessoas.

Comment: @Gandalf, o código deve abrangir também nomes com mais de 2 palavras?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 13):

Isto? Parece que o problema é que está tentando verificar coisa errada se tem mais de uma palavra.

```
public static boolean validacao(String nome) {
    return nome != null && !nome.isEmpty() && new StringTokenizer(nome).countTokens() > 1;
}
```

Depois de ver as soluções e ler documentação, fazer uns testes acho que esta forma é a mais simples e confiável porque foi feita para atender justamente esta demanda. Ainda não tenho certeza se tem *corner cases*.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/XxYX3R). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pytoevav-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/ValidName.java).

[`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Answer (score 7):

Uma sugestão com regex, que provavelmente vai aceitar acentuação e também irá trabalhar com CASE-INSENTIVE, seria usando assim:

```
public static boolean validacao(String nome){
    return nome != null && nome.matches("^\\p{L}+ [\\p{L} ]+$"));
}
```

Nem é necessário o `isEmpty` **nesse caso com REGEX**, se precisar de exatamente duas palavras mude apenas para:

```
nome.matches("^\\p{L}+ \\p{L}+$"))
```

Se não precisar de acentuação, então pode usar o `a-z`, o `\w` pode funcionar também, mas o problema dele é que ele aceita underscore `_`, e isso não me parece correto em uma validação de nome, então a regex pode ficar assim (usando o `(?i:...)` para case-insensitive pode ajudar a diminuir expressões regulares complexas):

```
public static boolean validacao(String nome){
    return nome != null && nome.matches("^(?i:[a-z]+ [a-z ]+)$"));
}
```

Se necessitar de exatamente 2 palavras mude para:

```
nome.matches("^(?i:[a-z]+ [a-z]+)$"))
```

Em ambos exemplos fiz aceitam um ou mais sobrenomes, ou seja duas ou mais palavras na string.

---

### Explicando as expressões regulares

Para a `^\\p{L}+ [\\p{L} ]+$`:

- `^` verifica se a expressão começa com
- `\\p{L}+` verifica palavras até encontrar um espaço (note que após o `+` tem um espaço)
- `[\\p{L} ]+$` verifica palavras e espaços, ou seja pode conter mais de uma palavra com espaço até encontrar o final da string

Para a `^(?i:[a-z]+ [a-z ]+)$`:

- `^` verifica se a expressão começa com
- `(?i:` inicia **um grupo** com case-insensitive
- `[a-z]+` verifica palavras com as letras de a-z até encontrar um espaço (note que após o `+` tem um espaço)
- `[a-z ]+)` verifica palavras com as letras de a-z e espaços, ou seja pode conter mais de uma palavra com espaço até encontrar o final **do grupo** (grupo para case-insensitive)
- `$` verifica se a string termina exatamente conforme a expressão

Answer (score 5):

`indexOf(" ")` retorna a posição em que o espaço está na `String`, portanto não necessariamente será `1`. O certo seria testar se o valor é diferente de `-1`, já que este é o valor retornado caso não haja espaços.

O problema é que `indexOf` só verifica se existe algum espaço em branco.
Se a entrada for `"     "` (vários espaços), por exemplo, ou se o espaço estiver no início ou no final, `indexOf` não vai adiantar nada.

Uma maneira de verificar se tem duas palavras é usar o que o [@Maniero sugere na resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/311378/112052). Outro jeito é usar expressão regular, para ter certeza que antes e depois do espaço você tem de fato uma palavra - assumindo que "palavra" é uma sequência de letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas:

```
public static boolean validacao(String nome){
    return (nome != null) && (! nome.isEmpty()) && nome.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$");
}
```

- `^` indica o início da `String`
- `[a-zA-Z]+` indica uma ou mais ocorrências de letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas
- `$` indica o início da `String`

Veja mais detalhes sobre expressão regular [neste tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).
Repare também que, como o retorno do método é um `boolean`, você pode retornar diretamente o resultado das verificações (conforme bem lembrado nos comentários).

Um detalhe é que a regex só vai funcionar para exatamente duas palavras. Mas você pode trocar o `$` por `.*`, que aí funciona para várias palavras (sendo que deve ter no mínimo duas).

E não vai aceitar caracteres acentuados, conforme apontado nos comentários.

Comment: Achei legal a ideia do regex, só que nomes podem conter mais de um sobrenome, tua regex só aceita um sobrenome, outra coisa, por que que tantos parenteses?

Comment: O `if` já é desnecessário. Basta retornar a própria comparação.

Comment: Outro detalhe, acentos não funcionarão com este tipo de regex a-zA-Z é só para letras sem acento.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Agora percebi meu erro com relação a duas palavras. Minha regex só validava exatamente duas palavras, mas a string pode ter mais. Editei a resposta, obrigado! E para os acentos, eu troquei a-zA-z por \w e funcionou, mas não sei se isso é algo que depende do Locale da JVM, então por enquanto deixei assim mesmo.

Comment: Creio que `\w` não trabalhe com acentos de forma "regular", o que complica tudo, pra evitar mais debate e eu conseguir mostrar-lhe o caminho mais rapidamente, uma sugestão que talvez atenda a tudo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15741/3635

Answer (score 0):

O problema é no indexOf, Ele vai retornar a posição do  espaço, que no casó é 7.

Acredito que a abordagem abaixo deve ser mais assertiva para encontrar a palavra com apenas um espaço

```
    public static boolean validacao(String nome){
        if(nome != null && !nome.isEmpty() && nome.split(" ").length == 2){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Se tiver 3 palavras dará falso negativo.

Comment: Porque return false e return true, isso é pura redundancia, dá pra vc por tudo dentro do return direto, outro detalhe, ==2 só irá permitir um nome e um sobrenome, se a pessoa tiver um sobrenome maior ai vai ser um problema.

Comment: Amigos, a descrição é a seguinte: "Se o parâmetro tiver duas partículas (duas palavras separadas por um espaço)". Não, mais de duas particulas...
Sim é redundante, mas fica mais amigavel a leitura para quem esta começando...

Comment: Inicialmente eu também tinha pensado que seriam exatamente duas partículas, mas pensando bem, o enunciado pode ser interpretado como "*pelo menos* duas"...

Comment: O código do Marlon cobre os casos que o autor levantou. Não entendo o motivo de dois negativos. Se tiver 3 palavras o nome será recusado, conforme esperado e, se este não fosse o caso, a correção seria simples.

Answer (score -2):

indexOf dará -1 ou o  espaço que a string mostrar o char desejado.
Na sua comparação ele só verifica que o espaço vem depois da primeira letra, exemplo: j joão daria certo, vc só precisa na sua comparação verificar se o indexOf(" ") é diferente de -1, logo:

```
public static boolean validacao(String nome){
         if ((nome != null) && (nome.isEmpty() == false) && (nome.indexOf(" ") != -1)){
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;
         }     
     }
```

Comment: Pra que tantos parenteses? Porque `== false`, um simples `!nome.isEmpty()` já não resolveria?

Comment: só copiei o código já escrito dele, mas concordo que possuí vários trechos de códigos desnecesários

Comment: Se o espaço for no começo ou no fim terá apenas um palavra e dará um falso positivo, portanto isto está errado.

Answer (score -2):

Gandalf, como está aprendendo, tomei a liberdade de ajustar o código original e fazer os testes necessários (muito importante).

Veja como ficou o código:

```
public static class NovoTeste2 {

    public static boolean validacao(String nome){
        return (nome != null) && (!nome.isEmpty()) && (nome.split(" ").length >= 2);
    }
}
```

No código acima, simplifiquei a verificação do nome estar vazio (não precisa do == false) e, para validar se o nome tem apenas duas palavras, fiz um split da String usando o espaço em branco, esperando que o array gerado pelo split tenha ao menos 2 elementos. Também alterei o nome da classe para um nome no padrão Java (usando CamelCase).

Se quiser restringir para **apenas duas palavras**, basta trocar de `length >= 2` para `length == 2`.

E por fim, o código acima com os testes para cada caso:

```
public class TemAoMenosDuasPalavrasTest {

    @Test
    public void nomeCorreto() {
        assertTrue(NovoTeste2.validacao("Augusto Nonato"));
    }

    @Test
    public void nomeComTresPalavras() {
        assertTrue(NovoTeste2.validacao("Augusto Nonato Junior"));
    }

    @Test
    public void nomeSemDuasPalavras() {
        assertFalse(NovoTeste2.validacao("Augusto"));
    }

    @Test
    public void nomeNulo() {
        assertFalse(NovoTeste2.validacao(null));
    }

    @Test
    public void nomeVazio() {
        assertFalse(NovoTeste2.validacao(""));
    }

    @Test
    public void nomeVazioComEspacos() {
        assertFalse(NovoTeste2.validacao("   "));
    }

    public static class NovoTeste2 {

        public static boolean validacao(String nome){
            return (nome != null) && (!nome.isEmpty()) && (nome.split(" ").length >= 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Assim, fica muito mais fácil saber se o seu código está funcionando mesmo após alterações e para todos os casos previstos.

Lembrando que não tratei todos os possíveis casos: nome válido com mais de um espaço entre as palavras, espaços extras no início ou final do nome, etc.

Comment: Dois negativos (um seguido do outro), sem explicarem o motivo e ainda adicionei testes para cobrir os casos levantados pelo autor da pergunta.

Comment: `"Augusto Nonato Junior"` daria falso, mas contém duas palavras sim. O autor não restringiu a validação a *"contém **exatamente** duas palavras"*, então seu codigo gera o mesmo problema da outra resposta.

Comment: @Articuno o título da pergunta está errado então? "Verificar se uma String contém **duas** palavras"

Comment: Não há erro no titulo nao, como eu disse, o autor **não** restringiu em momento algum que deveria ter exatamente duas palavras.

Comment: Então deveria ser "ao menos duas palavras".

Comment: @Articuno vou corrigir o título da pergunta (que está confuso) e o código acima.

Comment: Isso cabe ao autor definir melhor, mas como não definiu, foi o que foi entendido, já que não há menção a restrição.