# O preg_replace está cortando letras com acento

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '-', trim(strtolower($_POST["titulo"])));
```

Exemplo:

Eu envio: `Esse é um titulo de uma página`

Ele retorna: `esse-um-titulo-de-uma-p-gina`

Como você pode ver, está cortando as letras com acento.

Como deveria ser: `esse-e-um-titulo-de-uma-pagina`. Onde está o problema?

Answer (score 5):

Teu range no `[...]` esta de `a-z` e `0-9`, `a` até `z` só considera as letras do "alfabeto" e não suas variações, aliais trabalhar com acentos em URLs slug do meu ponto de vista é uma péssima ideia, seria mais interessante associar o slug a uma ID e url ser meramente ilustrativa e sem acentos, o que pode ser resolvido com funções como `iconv` do PHP, mas isso é opinião minha.

Os navegadores modernos hoje acreditam que trabalham com UTF-8 em suas urls, então talvez usar o range `\u00C0-\u00FF` funcione (como na resposta do renan: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15741/3635):

```
$slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF]+/ui', '-', trim(strtolower($_POST["titulo"])));
```

> Alguns navegadores antigos não trabalham com Unicode, por isto talvez o melhor seja usar a primeira sugestão, sem acentos, mas isso é uma história mais além, talvez em outra pergunta eu venha detalhar como fazer algo assim

Você pode até usar a resposta do *@bfavaretto*: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15740/3635 tem que ter em mente que os acentos podem não funcionar, pois se o documento `.php` for salvo com ANSI ou iso-8859-1/windows-1252 então vai falhar com certeza, acaso queira ainda sim usar como na resposta do *@bfavaretto* recomendo que antes leia esta resposta com toda a calma:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Depois de ler e entender como usar o utf-8 adequadamente pode tentar isto:

```
$slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9áàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]+/i', '-', trim(strtolower($_POST["titulo"])));
```

Comment: Eu fiz todas as suas instruções que estão no link sobre o utf-8, e não resolveu esse erro: `Úm titulo página` e o slug fica `-m-titulo-p-?gina`. Eu também tentei usar o `\u00C0-\u00FF` mas recebi um erro: `Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 9` Eu vi que aqui no SO existem perguntas sobre isso, mas cada um fala algo diferente... e não consegui tirar esse erro.

Comment: @Natalie desculpe, esqueci da flag `u`, mude isto `/[^a-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF]+/i` para isto `/[^a-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF]+/ui`

Comment: Eu vou aceitar sua dica e usar ID no URL, eu segui todas as suas instruções mas não resolveu o problema.

Comment: @Natalie não resolveu como? Isso é vago para entender, descreva o que ocorreu de falha.

Comment: Continuo com os mesmos erros que descrevi no primeiro comentário que fiz na sua resposta.

Comment: @Natalie por favor mostre o que exatamente você fez, porque eu postei mais de um código. Da maneira que você fala eu não consigo ver e nem entender qual dos códigos falhou, se foi um ou todos, ou se você fez algo errado.

Comment: Primeiro eu li a sua resposta sobre utf-8 que esta nesse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635, e usei o seu código: `$slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9áàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]+/i', '-', trim(strtolower($_POST["titulo"])));`, mas o slug não ficou como o esperado: `Úm titulo página` = `-m-titulo-p-?gina`. Em seguida eu tentei usar o `preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF]+/ui'`, mas quando eu envio os dados do input para o DB mostra um erro: `Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 9`.

Comment: @Natalie mas isso não funcionou `'/[^a-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF]+/ui'`?

Comment: Não, mostrou o erro: `Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 9`.

Comment: @Natalie vc adicionou o `u` após o `/` ou não?

Comment: Não entendi, eu coloquei o código que está na sua resposta. `$slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF]+/ui', '-', trim(strtolower($_POST["titulo"])));`

Comment: @Natalie duas perguntas: **1.** qual versão do PHP? **2.** com `/[^a-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF]+/ui` ocorre o erro "Compilation failed: PCRE"?

Comment: **1 -** php 7.2 ,**2 -** Sim.

Answer (score -3):

`preg_replace`: Realiza uma pesquisa por uma expressão regular e a substitui.

Então basicamente, o que você está passando é, `'/[^a-z0-9]+/i'` tudo que não estiver dentro desse escopo, substitui por `'-'`.

O correto seria `'/[^a-zà-ú0-9]+/i'`:

```
$slug = preg_replace('/[^a-zà-ú0-9]+/i', '-', trim(strtolower($_POST["titulo"])));
```

Comment: Caro Jonathan queira me perdoar, o downvote é meu, não é por mal, todos meus downvotes é quando realmente existe um problema técnico em uma resposta, é o caso da sua. Acentos tem problemas porque existem diversas codificações, sendo as duas comuns em web utf-8 e windows-1252, da forma que fez não existem garantias de funcionar, aliais pode falhar muito facilmente, antes de trabalhar com acentos é necessário que a pessoa entenda como funcionam os codecs [...]

Comment: [...]  Espero que entenda que isto é uma avaliação técnica e não pessoal e o downvote representa uma indicação que esta solução não é a ideal e pode causar problema para quem chegar a esta pergunta. Desejo-lhe uma otima tarde.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, e feedback desta forma não tem como levar para o lado pessoal, vou tentar melhorar minhas futuras respostas. Vlw

Comment: Obrigado Jon, acredite sempre comento mais ou menos assim, mas mesmo assim tem usuários que já levaram muito a mal, até mesmo alguns certos candidatos a moderador da eleição atual.