# Como criar um regex para apagar letras e número depois da 3ª casa decimal

Tags: angular, regex

Preciso de uma expressão regular com as seguintes regras:

- Apagar tudo que é letra
- Apagar tudo que é número depois da 3ª casa decimal

Por exemplo, se eu digitar `34,444` qualquer próximo número será apagado. Se eu digitar `a` também será apagado.

```
 $scope.validateLimits = function(){
    $scope.numLimiteInferior = $scope.numLimiteInferior.replace(/\d|,/g,'');
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex que você usou (`/\d|,/`) significa "um dígito ou uma vírgula", o que significa que você está substituindo os números e as vírgulas por `''` (ou seja, está removendo todos os números e vírgulas da string).

---

Sugiro fazer por partes: primeiro remova as letras e depois remova as casas decimais:

```js
let x = '3b4,4444444a';
x = x.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(,\d{3})\d+/, '$1');
console.log(x); // 34,444
```

Para letras eu usei `[a-zA-Z]` (qualquer letra de `a` a `z`, maiúscula ou minúscula).

Para as casas decimais eu usei parênteses para formar [um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), e dentro deles coloquei `,\d{3}` (vírgula seguida 3 números). Como esta parte está dentro de parênteses, caso exista uma vírgula seguida de 3 números, eles farão parte do grupo de captura. E como é o primeiro par de parênteses, então será o primeiro grupo.

Depois tem `\d+` (um ou mais dígitos), e em vez de substituir pela string vazia, eu uso a referência `$1`, que significa "tudo que corresponde ao primeiro grupo de captura". No nosso caso, é a vírgula seguida de 3 dígitos. Sendo assim, eu mantenho a vírgula e os 3 dígitos seguintes, e elimino todos os números da quarta casa decimal em diante.

Repare também que para remover as letras eu uso a [*flag* `g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters), pois assim todas as letras são removidas. Já na segunda regex eu não uso o `g`, pois estou assumindo que só haverá uma vírgula seguida de números.

Além disso, a regex `/[a-zA-Z]/g` não considera letras acentuadas. Se quiser, pode mudá-la para `/[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]/ig` (com a opção `i` para aceitar tantos maiúsculas quanto minúsculas, assim ela fica mais curta). Se quiser, [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15738/112052) tem outras opções de regex para letras acentuadas.