# RegEx para frase completa em letras maiúsculas

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou percorrendo a primeira coluna do corpo de uma tabela HTML e extraindo o texto de cada uma das células usando JavaScript e testando contra uma RegEx.

A RegEx tem a função de identificar quais frases ou *strings* (conteúdo de cada célula) são formadas, exclusivamente, por palavras com **todas as letras** maiúsculas, ignorando caracteres especiais, exceto acentos nas letras, sinais de pontuação e símbolos matemáticos.

Enfrento dificuldades em encontrar a RegEx correta para os seguintes casos amostrais em JavaScript, que representam o todo adequadamente. À esquerda, temos o texto que é extraído da tabela e, à direita, temos o resultado que deveria ser retornado pela função `.test()` do JavaScript:

```
(+/-) Provisão Despesas Administrativas - DPVAT ---------- false
PRÊMIOS EMITIDOS(-) PLANOS DE APOSENTADORIA -------------- true
(+) Prêmios - Riscos Vigentes Não Emitidos --------------- false
(+) OUTRAS RECEITAS E DESPESAS OPERACIONAIS -------------- true
(=) LUCRO LÍQUIDO / PREJUÍZO ----------------------------- true
CIRCULANTE ----------------------------------------------- true
(-) Redução ao valor recuperável ------------------------- false
Operações com Resseguradoras ----------------------------- false
ATIVOS DE RESSEGURO E RETROCESSÃO - PROVISÕES TÉCNICAS --- true
Prêmios Diferidos - PPNG --------------------------------- false
**********TOTAL DO ATIVO********** ----------------------- true
```

No entanto, a RegEx que eu inclui na função `isUpperCase()` abaixo, não trata corretamente os casos acima, considerando `true`, por exemplo, o valor `"Prêmios Diferidos - PPNG"`, quando este deveria ser `false`.

A Função 1 abaixo testa a *string* contra a RegEx e a Função 2 adiciona formatação ao texto, caso todas as palavras da célula sejam todas em maiúsculas. Ambas são executadas corretamente, dada a limitação da RegEx.

**Função 1 - isUpperCase()**

```
const isUpperCase = ( str ) => {
    // RegEx contra a qual a palavra será testada
    // FIX
    return (/[A-ZÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ]{3}/).test(str);
}
```

**Função 2 - addFormatting()**

```
const addFormatting = ( table ) => {
    let tableElement = document.querySelector('.' + table);
    let cellCollection = tableElement.querySelectorAll('tbody tr > td:first-child');

    cellCollection.forEach( function ( cell ) {
        if( isUpperCase( cell.innerText ) ) {
            cell.parentNode.setAttribute(
                "style",
                `color: rgb(0, 92, 169);
                padding-left: -15px;
                font-weight: bold;`
            )
        } else {
            cell.style.paddingLeft = "32px";
        }
    });
}
```

Preciso de ajuda para encontrar a RegEx apropriada para os casos em destaque, que seria suficiente para o meu caso de uso e minha situação específica.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma solução seria eliminar tudo que não é letra, e depois testar se o que sobrou só tem letras maiúsculas:

```js
function isUpperCase(s) {
    return /^[A-Z]+$/.test(s.normalize('NFD').replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ''));
}

[ 
   '(+/-) Provisão Despesas Administrativas - DPVAT', 
   'PRÊMIOS EMITIDOS(-) PLANOS DE APOSENTADORIA', 
   '(+) Prêmios - Riscos Vigentes Não Emitidos', 
   '(+) OUTRAS RECEITAS E DESPESAS OPERACIONAIS', 
   '(=) LUCRO LÍQUIDO / PREJUÍZO', 
   'CIRCULANTE', 
   '(-) Redução ao valor recuperável', 
   'Operações com Resseguradoras', 
   'ATIVOS DE RESSEGURO E RETROCESSÃO - PROVISÕES TÉCNICAS', 
   'Prêmios Diferidos - PPNG', 
   '**********TOTAL DO ATIVO**********'
].forEach(s => {
    console.log(`${s} = ${isUpperCase(s)}`);
});
```

Eu usei [`normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) para converter a string para a forma NFD. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052) tem uma explicação mais detalhada sobre o seu funcionamento, mas basicamente caracteres como o `á` (letra `a` com acento) são "quebrados" (decompostos) em dois: a letra `a` sem acento e o próprio acento.

Depois eu uso [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), que remove `[^A-Za-z]` (qualquer coisa que **não** seja uma letra de `a` a `z`, maiúscula ou minúscula) - na verdade eu substituo esses caracteres por `''` (string vazia), o que é o mesmo que removê-los, e a [flag `g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags_2) garante que todas as ocorrências são removidas. Graças à normalização para NFD, os acentos também são eliminados (tal como feito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406366/112052)), pois o `á` foi quebrado em `a` e `´`, e o acento é eliminado. Portanto, o que sobra são apenas letras maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Depois eu uso [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) com a regex `^[A-Z]+$`: os [marcadores](http://rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#caret) `^` e `$` indicam respectivamente o início e fim da string, e `[A-Z]+` verifica se há [uma ou mais](http://rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet) letras maiúsculas.

Ou seja, o `normalize` junto com `replace` elimina os acentos e tudo que não for letra, e depois eu testo se o que sobrou só tem letras maiúsculas.

---

Existe uma opção (que ainda não funciona em todos os browsers), que é usar [*Unicode Property Escapes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes):

```js
// *** Não funciona no Firefox e IE ***
function isUpperCase(s) {
    return /^\p{Lu}+$/u.test(s.replace(/\P{L}/ug, ''));
}

[ 
   '(+/-) Provisão Despesas Administrativas - DPVAT', 
   'PRÊMIOS EMITIDOS(-) PLANOS DE APOSENTADORIA', 
   '(+) Prêmios - Riscos Vigentes Não Emitidos', 
   '(+) OUTRAS RECEITAS E DESPESAS OPERACIONAIS', 
   '(=) LUCRO LÍQUIDO / PREJUÍZO', 
   'CIRCULANTE', 
   '(-) Redução ao valor recuperável', 
   'Operações com Resseguradoras', 
   'ATIVOS DE RESSEGURO E RETROCESSÃO - PROVISÕES TÉCNICAS', 
   'Prêmios Diferidos - PPNG', 
   '**********TOTAL DO ATIVO**********'
].forEach(s => {
    console.log(`${s} = ${isUpperCase(s)}`);
});
```

A lógica é a mesma da regex anterior, mas agora eu uso as *Unicode properties*. No caso, eu removo tudo que não é letra (`\P{L}`), e verifico se o que sobrou é somente letras maiúsculas (`\p{Lu}`). Neste caso não precisa normalizar a string, mas vale lembrar que as categorias Unicode são bem abrangentes e consideram letras de outros alfabetos (como o japonês, árabe, cirílico, grego, etc). Se não quiser ser tão abrangente e considerar somente o nosso alfabeto, use a solução anterior (ou a alternativa abaixo, sem regex).

Repare que neste caso as regex devem ter a [*flag* `u`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags_2) habilitada, para que os *Unicode Properties* sejam reconhecidos corretamente.

Vale lembrar ainda que [segundo a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Browser_compatibility), o Firefox e IE ainda não suportam esta sintaxe (o que pode ser mais um motivo para não usar - só deixei aqui como informação adicional mesmo).

---

#### Sem regex

Também dá para resolver sem regex, apenas testando os caracteres da string um a um:

```js
function isUpperCase(s) {
    s = s.normalize('NFD');
    let hasUpper = false; // verifica se tem pelo menos uma letra maiúscula
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        let c = s.codePointAt(i);

        // se for letra maiúscula, marca que encontrou
        if (65 <= c && c <= 90) hasUpper = true;

        // se for letra minúscula, já retorna false
        if (97 <= c && c <= 122) return false;
    }

    return hasUpper;
}

[ 
   '(+/-) Provisão Despesas Administrativas - DPVAT', 
   'PRÊMIOS EMITIDOS(-) PLANOS DE APOSENTADORIA', 
   '(+) Prêmios - Riscos Vigentes Não Emitidos', 
   '(+) OUTRAS RECEITAS E DESPESAS OPERACIONAIS', 
   '(=) LUCRO LÍQUIDO / PREJUÍZO', 
   'CIRCULANTE', 
   '(-) Redução ao valor recuperável', 
   'Operações com Resseguradoras', 
   'ATIVOS DE RESSEGURO E RETROCESSÃO - PROVISÕES TÉCNICAS', 
   'Prêmios Diferidos - PPNG', 
   '**********TOTAL DO ATIVO**********'
].forEach(s => {
    console.log(`${s} = ${isUpperCase(s)}`);
});
```

Eu continuo convertendo a string para a forma NFD para eliminar os acentos, e em seguida uso [`codePointAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) para obter cada codepoint da string. Para entender melhor o que é um codepoint, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052). Para simplificar, as letras de A a Z possuem codepoints com os mesmos valores da [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/), então na verificação basta comparar com esses valores.

Se tiver alguma letra minúscula, já retorno `false`. Se encontrei pelo menos uma letra maiúscula, retorna `true` (se não encontrou nenhuma, o retorno é `false`). Qualquer outro caractere que não seja letra é ignorado (graças à normalização para NFD, o acento também é ignorado, pois a letra `á` é decomposta em `a` e `´`, ou seja, a letra é considerada, mas o acento não).

Comment: Excelente! Adorei sua explicação também! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

A resposta o @hkotsubo é muito boa e abrange qualquer tipo de situação caso haja possibilidade do texto conter letras acentuadas que não fazem parte do português (ex.: ĕ, ö, ă etc.).

Porém gostaria de deixar uma solução um pouco mais simples caso os textos sejam apenas em português, onde não precisará usar o `.mormalize()` e o `.replace()`, usando a regex:

```
/[a-zà-ü]/
```

Essa expressão irá abranger os caracteres:

```
a-z -> de "a" a "z" minúsculas
à-ü -> à, á, â, ã, ä, å, æ, ç, è, é, ê, ë, ì, í, î,
       ï, ð, ñ, ò, ó, ô, õ, ö, ÷, ø, ù, ú, û, ü
```

Muitos desses caracteres não fazem parte do português, mas como eu quero pegar do `à` a `ü` em sequência da tabela [Unicode](https://unicode-table.com/en/#00FC), fica mais simples usar `à-ü` do que fatiar a sequência. Se bem que o `ü` (letra `u` com trema) foi removido do português brasileiro moderno, mas incluí ele para garantir caso haja também.

No `if` que verifica a função `isUpperCase()`, você faz uma verificação negativa adicionando o `!` antes do nome da função:

```
if( !isUpperCase( cell.innerText ) ) {
    ↑
```

O `return /[a-zà-ü]/.test(str);` irá retornar `true` se o texto tiver qualquer um desses caracteres minúsculos -- incluindo todas as letras acentuadas do português brasileiro --, ou seja, indicando que há pelo menos uma letra minúscula no texto. Como você está fazendo uma verificação negativa, é preciso também trocar o código do `else` pelo do `if` e vice-versa.

**Teste:**

```js
const isUpperCase = ( str ) => {
    // RegEx contra a qual a palavra será testada
    // FIX
    return /[a-zà-ü]/.test(str);
}

const addFormatting = ( table ) => {
    let tableElement = document.querySelector('.' + table);
    let cellCollection = tableElement.querySelectorAll('tbody tr > td:first-child');

    cellCollection.forEach( function ( cell ) {
        if( !isUpperCase( cell.innerText ) ) {
           cell.nextElementSibling.textContent = "true"; // apague esta linha
            cell.style.paddingLeft = "32px";
        } else {
           cell.nextElementSibling.textContent = "false"; // apague esta linha
            cell.parentNode.setAttribute(
                "style",
                `color: rgb(0, 92, 169);
                padding-left: -15px;
                font-weight: bold;`
            )
        }
    });
}

addFormatting("tabela");
```

```html
<table border="1" class="tabela">
   <tr>
      <td>
         (+/-) Provisão Despesas Administrativas - DPVAT
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         PRÊMIOS EMITIDOS(-) PLANOS DE APOSENTADORIA
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         (+) Prêmios - Riscos Vigentes Não Emitidos
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         (+) OUTRAS RECEITAS E DESPESAS OPERACIONAIS
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         (=) LUCRO LÍQUIDO / PREJUÍZO
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         CIRCULANTE
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         (-) Redução ao valor recuperável
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         Operações com Resseguradoras
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         ATIVOS DE RESSEGURO E RETROCESSÃO - PROVISÕES TÉCNICAS
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         Prêmios Diferidos - PPNG
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         **********TOTAL DO ATIVO**********
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Só um detalhe: o intervalo `à-ü` também considera outros caracteres "estranhos", como o [`æ`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e6/index.htm) e o [`÷`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f7/index.htm), entre outros ([lista completa](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/list.htm)) - se bem que é melhor sobrar que faltar mesmo. E ele tb não considera os casos em que os acentos estão em NFD ([exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/rskD0b/1/)). Eu tb mudaria o nome da função, pois agora ela faz o oposto de `isUpperCase` :-) De qq forma, +1

Comment: Rs... Vc é mt perfeccionista, e eu admiro isso. Tb sou um pouco, mas não tanto rs.. Valeu amigo!