# Regex para aceitar acentos na primeira letra e última letra do nome e sobrenome

Tags: javascript, regex, acentuação

Estou tentando criar um regex em JavaScript que aceite letras e acentos na primeira e última letra:

```
var exp = /^((\b[A-zÀ-ú']{2,40}\b)\s*){2,}$/gm;
    var re = new RegExp(exp);

    if(nome.match(re))...
```

Exemplo: Álvaro Silva, Ítalo José ou Érica Santos.

Comment: @hkotsubo Não porque preciso que tenha um sobrenome e nesses Regex eu válido os acentos mas não forço a colocação do sobrenome, mas obrigado!

Comment: Realmente, ontem eu achei que o problema era só saber como achar os caracteres acentuados.  Mas investigando melhor vi que era outra coisa (deixei uma resposta abaixo)

Answer (score 2):

O problema da sua regex é o [atalho `\b`](https://regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Ele indica uma *word boundary* ("fronteira de palavra"), ou seja, uma posição que possui um caractere alfanumérico antes e um não-alfanumérico depois (ou vice-versa, [veja aqui uma explicação mais detalhada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/420506/112052)).

O problema é que a definição do que é alfanumérico varia muito entre as linguagens, API's e *engines* de regex. Alguns consideram todas as letras e dígitos definidas pelo [Unicode](http://unicode.org/) (ou seja, englobam todos os alfabetos existentes no mundo), enquanto outros se restringem ao [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) (apenas letras de "a" a "z" maiúsculas e minúsculas, dígitos de 0 a 9, e o caractere `_`). No caso do JavaScript, adivinhe só, caracteres acentuados não são considerados "word characters".

Dá para fazer um teste simples:

```js
console.log('Álvaro'.split(/\b/)); // [ 'Á', 'lvaro' ]
```

O `split` é feito no `\b` (ou seja, na posição em que há um caractere alfanumérico antes e um não-alfanumérico depois, ou vice-versa). E como o caractere acentuado `Á` não é considerado alfanumérico, e logo depois dele tem um alfanumérico (a letra `l`), foi feita a quebra nesta posição.

---

Sendo assim, `\b` não vai funcionar no seu caso. Se a string começa com um caractere acentuado, a posição anterior a ele (o início da string) não corresponde a `\b` (pois como explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/420506/112052), o início da string é considerada uma "posição que não tem um caractere alfanumérico", então um caractere acentuado no início é considerado uma posição que tem um caractere não-alfanumérico antes (o início da string) e um não-alfanumérico depois (a letra acentuada)).

O jeito é não usar `\b`, e em vez disso, indicar que depois das letras você só pode ter espaços ou o final da string:

```js
let exp = /^([a-zA-ZÀ-ú']{2,40}(\s+|$)){2,}$/;
[ 'Álvaro Silva', 'Ítalo José', 'Érica Santos', 'SemSobrenome' ].forEach(s => {
    console.log(`${s}: ${exp.test(s)}`);
});
```

Depois do nome eu coloco `(\s+|$)` (o [quantificador](http://regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` indica "um ou mais" e o caractere `|` indica [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), então este trecho significa "um ou mais espaços **ou** o final da string"). Você estava usando `\s*`, que significa "zero ou mais espaços", o que poderia pegar casos que não tem sobrenome. Forçando pelo menos um espaço eu garanto que tem que ter algo depois (e o quantificador `{2,}` garante que isso deve se repetir pelo menos duas vezes). Com isso, eu aceito nomes com acentos, e força a ter pelo menos um sobrenome.

Repare que ao criar uma expressão com `/^etc.../`, você já tem uma instância de [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), pois [a expressão entre barras é a forma literal de se criar uma regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Literal_notation_and_constructor). Não precisa fazer `new RegExp(exp)`, pois `exp` já é uma regex e você pode usá-lo diretamente. Vi também que você usou `string.match(regex)`, mas se você só quer saber se a string corresponde à regex (apenas "sim" ou "não"), pode usar `regex.test(string)` ([`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) retorna um array contendo os resultados da busca, enquanto [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) retorna apenas `true` ou `false`, que parece ser o que você precisa).

Também troquei `A-z` por `a-zA-Z`. Isso porque o intervalo `A-z` acaba pegando outros caracteres que não são letras, como o `[` e `\`, por exemplo. Veja a diferença:

```js
let s = "a[\\]b";
console.log(s.match(/[A-z]+/g)); // [ 'a[\\]b' ]
console.log(s.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)); // [ 'a', 'b' ]
```

---

Também removi as [*flags*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags) `g` e `m`, pois não parecem ser necessárias. A *flag* `g` serve para buscar todas as ocorrências em uma string (pois por padrão, somente a primeira ocorrência é retornada). Se a string tem mais de um nome e você quer buscar todos, aí faz sentido usá-la. Se a string só tem um único nome, não fará diferença ter o `g`.

E a *flag* `m` serve para mudar o comportamento dos [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`. Por padrão eles correspondem apenas ao início e fim da string, mas com a *flag* `m` eles também passam a considerar o início e fim de uma linha. Se você estiver buscando em uma string que contém um nome por linha, aí faz sentido usá-la (juntamente com `g` se quiser todas as ocorrências). Mas se estiver tudo em uma única linha, aí não precisa da *flag* e nem dos marcadores. Ex:

```js
let exp = /^([a-zA-ZÀ-ú']{2,40}( +|$)){2,}$/gm;
let nomes = 'Álvaro Silva\nÍtalo José\nÉrica Santos\nSemSobrenome';
console.log(nomes.match(exp)); // [ 'Álvaro Silva', 'Ítalo José', 'Érica Santos' ]
```

No exemplo acima, cada nome está em uma linha, e usei as *flags* `m` (para que `^` e `$` também considerem o início e fim de linha) e `g` (para que `match` retorne todas as ocorrências). Eu só tive que trocar o `\s` por um espaço (repare que há um espaço antes do `+`), porque [`\s` também considera outros caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052), inclusive as quebras de linha, então ele estava considerando que a string inteira era um único nome. Trocando-o por espaços eu evito este problema.

Agora se a string só tem um único nome, as *flags* não farão diferença.

---

Outro ponto é que você mencionou que deve aceitar acentos na primeira e última letra. Bem, se for **somente** na primeira ou última, aí teria que adaptar um pouco:

```js
let exp = /^([a-zA-ZÀ-ú][a-zA-Z]{0,38}[a-zA-ZÀ-ú]( +|$)){2,}$/gm;
let nomes = 'Álvaro Silva\nÍtalo José\nÉrica Santos\nSemSobrenome\nAcentos Estão no Meio';
console.log(nomes.match(exp)); // [ 'Álvaro Silva', 'Ítalo José', 'Érica Santos' ]
```

Agora eu coloco os acentos apenas na primeira e última letra, e entre eles eu deixo apenas as letras não acentuadas. Mudei as quantidades para `{0,38}`, porque antes você estava usando `{2,40}` (no mínimo 2, no máximo 40), mas como agora a primeira e última letra estão colocadas explicitamente, o meio terá entre 0 e 38 caracteres.

Outro detalhe é que o intervalo `À-ú` inclui alguns caracteres que não são letras acentuadas, como por exemplo o [`Æ`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c6/index.htm) e o [`÷` (DIVISION SIGN)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f7/index.htm), além de deixar de fora o `ü` (que é usado em nomes alemães, por exemplo) - [veja aqui](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/list.htm) a lista completa. Além disso, sua regex tem um apóstrofo ali no meio, não sei se faz sentido, então retirei.

Para uma regex que contemple acentos, existem outras alternativas listadas [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15738/112052) (vale mencionar a possibilidade de "esquisitices" como a normalização Unicode, e se quiser se aprofundar, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406366/112052)).

---

Outra alternativa é usar [*lookarounds*](https://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) para verificar se algo existe antes ou depois de determinado trecho:

```js
let exp = /^(((?<![a-zA-ZÀ-ü])[a-zA-ZÀ-ü]{2,40}(?![a-zA-ZÀ-ü]))( +|$)){2,}$/gm;
let nomes = 'Álvaro Silva\nÍtalo José\nÉrica Santos\nSemSobrenome\nAcentos Estão no Meio';
console.log(nomes.match(exp)); // [ 'Álvaro Silva', 'Ítalo José', 'Érica Santos', 'Acentos Estão no Meio' ]
```

O trecho `(?<![a-zA-ZÀ-ü])` é um *lookbehind* negativo, que verifica se algo **não** existe antes de determinada posição. No caso, estou verificando se não existe uma letra antes. De forma similar, `(?![a-zA-ZÀ-ü])` é um *lookahead* negativo, que verifica se algo **não** existe depois.

Ou seja, eu busco pelas letras, desde que antes e depois não haja uma letra, seja ela acentuada ou não (é uma forma de simular o `\b`, porém considerando também as letras acentuadas).

---

Outra opção (que [ainda não é compatível com todos os browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Browser_compatibility), então avalie se faz sentido no seu caso) é usar [*Unicode property escapes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes):

```js
// aceita acentos em qualquer parte do nome
let exp = /^(\p{L}{2,40}( +|$)){2,}$/ugm;
let nomes = 'Álvaro Silva\nÍtalo José\nÉrica Santos\nSemSobrenome\nAcentos Estão no Meio';
console.log(nomes.match(exp)); // [ 'Álvaro Silva', 'Ítalo José', 'Érica Santos', 'Acentos Estão no Meio' ]

// aceita acentos apenas no início e fim
exp = /^((\p{L}\p{M}*)\p{L}{0,38}(\p{L}\p{M}*)( +|$)){2,}$/ugm;
console.log(nomes.normalize('NFD').match(exp)); // [ 'Álvaro Silva', 'Ítalo José', 'Érica Santos' ]
```

Basicamente, `\p{L}` aceita qualquer letra definida pelo Unicode, incluindo as acentuadas. Repare que precisa da *flag* `u`, que habilita o "modo Unicode".

Já para aceitar os acentos somente no início ou fim, usei a normalização (veja mais detalhes sobre isso lendo [aqui](/q/406545/112052), [aqui](/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](/a/345946/112052)). Mas basicamente, ao normalizar para NFD, letras como `Á` são "quebradas" em duas: a letra `A` sem acento e o próprio acento. Assim, `\p{L}` pega a letra e `\p{M}` pega os acentos (zero ou mais, no caso). Já no meio da string eu não considero os acentos, então no fim a regex só aceita acentos no início e fim do nome.

Só que agora ficou abrangente demais, pois `\p{L}` considera vários outros alfabetos, como o japonês, árabe, cirílico, etc (basicamente, todos os que pertencem às categorias que começam com "L" [desta lista](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)). Se quiser considerar somente o nosso alfabeto (e o browser suportar este recurso), pode trocar `\p{L}` por `\p{Script=Latin}`.