# Como retirar caractere especial da classe obtida de um texto?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando esse código para passar o texto de um label para classe:

```
$('label').each(function() {
    const el = $(this);
    el.addClass( 'pay-' + el.text() );
});
```

No entanto, preciso utilizar palavras com acentuação, o que acaba a inutilizando.

```
<label for="P1386_ID_FORMA_MEIO_1" class="pay-Cartão">Cartão</label>
```

com eu poderia remover a acentuação apenas da classe criada?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406366/112052

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode [normalizar a string](https://metring.com.br/javascript-substituir-caracteres-especiais) utilizando uma função do javascript ES6.

```
const textoNormalizado = el.text().normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
```